# Making Selenium IDE record clicks on objects with jquery click handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium to record test scripts for a web application.

Some pages in the application contain tables which represent lists of records in a database. There is a jquery click handler attached to the table rows, which loads a page allowing the user to edit the relevant record when they click on the table row.

Unfortunately Selenium IDE does not record clicks on table rows. I have looked at the code, and the relevant function is:

```
Recorder.prototype.findClickableElement = function(e) {
    if (!e.tagName) return null;
    var tagName = e.tagName.toLowerCase();
    var type = e.type;
    if (e.hasAttribute("onclick") || e.hasAttribute("href") || tagName == "button" ||
        (tagName == "input" && 
         (type == "submit" || type == "button" || type == "image" || type == "radio" || type == "checkbox" || type == "reset"))) {
        return e;
    } else {
        if (e.parentNode != null) {
            return this.findClickableElement(e.parentNode);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to modify this, by adding the following:

```
if($ && $._data) {
    var ev = $._data(e, "events");
    if(ev && ev.click)
        return e;
}
```

However, $._data is null!

If I look at the same variable in Firebug, with the same web page open, $._data exists, and  $._data(e, "events").click also exists.

I am not sure why it is there in Firebug, but not in Selenium. Is it possible that Selenium is running in a different context, so there are 2 different "$" variables, or something?